# Stuck on Project Euler #3 in python

Tags: python, math, primes

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. What is the largest
> prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Ok, so i am working on project euler problem 3 in python. I am kind of confused. I can't tell if the answers that i am getting with this program are correct or not. If somone could please tell me what im doing wrong it would be great!

```py
#import pdb

odd_list=[]
prime_list=[2] #Begin with zero so that we can pop later without errors.

#Define a function that finds all the odd numbers in the range of a number
def oddNumbers(x):

  x+=1 #add one to the number because range does not include it
  for i in range(x):
     if i%2!=0: #If it cannot be evenly divided by two it is eliminated
        odd_list.append(i) #Add it too the list
    
  return odd_list 

def findPrimes(number_to_test, list_of_odd_numbers_in_tested_number): # Pass in the prime number to test
   for i in list_of_odd_numbers_in_tested_number:
     if number_to_test % i==0:
       prime_list.append(i)
       number_to_test=number_to_test / i
          
       #prime_list.append(i)
       #prime_list.pop(-2) #remove the old number so that we only have the biggest

       if prime_list==[1]:
           print "This has no prime factors other than 1"
       else:
           print prime_list
       return prime_list
        
    #pdb.set_trace()

    number_to_test=raw_input("What number would you like to find the greatest prime of?\n:")

    #Convert the input to an integer
    number_to_test=int(number_to_test)

    #Pass the number to the oddnumbers function
    odds=oddNumbers(number_to_test)

#Pass the return of the oddnumbers function to the findPrimes function
findPrimes(number_to_test , odds)
```

Comment: Its not neccessary that every one has solved `Project Euler # 3`. At least post the problem statement here. And you need to tell us what's the problem with your code, rather than asking anyone.

Comment: _"I can't tell if the answers that i am getting with this program are correct or not."_ Testing a factorization program is easy: just multiply the factors and see if the result matches the original number.

Comment: try the sieve algorithm for primes, otherwise brute force is going to take a long long time for `600851475143`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary brute force should take no more than few seconds for this problem, if you (correctly) stop at 775146.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- the number `600851475143` is big to discourage you to use brute-force.
- the `oddNumbers` function in going to put `600851475143 / 2` numbers in `odd_list`, that's **a lot** of memory.
- checking that a number can be divided by an odd number does not mean the odd number is a prime number. the algorithm you provided is wrong.
- there are a lot of mathematical/algorithm tricks about prime numbers, you should and search them online then *sieve through* the answers. you might also get *to the root* of the problem to make sure you have *squared away* some of the issues.

you could use a generator to get the list of odds (not that it will help you):

```
odd_list = xrange(1, number+1, 2)
```

here are the concepts needed to deal with prime numbers:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

if you are **really** stuck, then there are solutions already there:

- [Project Euler #3, infinite loop on factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350694/project-euler-3-infinite-loop-on-factorization)
- [Project Euler 3 - Why does this method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605320/project-euler-3-why-does-this-method-work)
- [Project Euler Question 3 Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201374/project-euler-question-3-help)

Comment: even [brute-force works](http://ideone.com/fbv5V4) for such small numbers. +1 for "sieve through answer" and "squared away"

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution is trial division. Let's work through the factorization of 13195, then you can apply that method to the larger number that interests you.

Start with a trial divisor of 2; 13195 divided by 2 leaves a remainder of 1, so 2 does not divide 13195, and we can go on to the next trial divisor. Next we try 3, but that leaves a remainder of 1; then we try 4, but that leaves a remainder of 3. The next trial divisor is 5, and that does divide 13195, so we output 5 as a factor of 13195, reduce the original number to 2639 = 13195 / 5, and try 5 again. Now 2639 divided by 5 leaves a remainder of 4, so we advance to 6, which leaves a remainder of 5, then we advance to 7, which does divide 2639, so we output 7 as a factor of 2639 (and also a factor of 13195) and reduce the original number again to 377 = 2639 / 7. Now we try 7 again, but it fails to divide 377, as does 8, and 9, and 10, and 11, and 12, but 13 divides 2639. So we output 13 as a divisor of 377 (and of 2639 and 13195) and reduce the original number again to 29 = 377 / 13. As this point we are finished, because the square of the trial divisor, which is still 13, is greater than the remaining number, 29, which proves that 29 is prime; that is so because if *n=pq*, then either *p* or *q* must be less than, or equal to the square root of n, and since we have tried all those divisors, the remaining number, 29, must be prime. Thus, 13195 = 5 * 7 * 13 * 29.

Here's a pseudocode description of the algorithm:

```
function factors(n)
    f = 2
    while f * f <= n
        if f divides n
            output f
            n = n / f
        else
            f = f + 1
    output n
```

There are better ways to factor integers. But this method is sufficient for Project Euler #3, and for many other factorization projects as well. If you want to learn more about prime numbers and factorization, I modestly recommend the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which among other things has a python implementation of the algorithm described above.

Comment: 92365 = 5 * 7 * 7 * 13 * 29 would be a better choice to showcase the algorithm IMO. :) But kudos for the clear and detailed exposition!

Comment: @user448810  Thanks so much!  With a slight mod your code is what I need to implement the matlab factor() operation, which has no scipy/numpy analog.  Brilliant!

Comment: very clear and simple explanation, thanks. But can you expound what you mean by this?

**because the square of the trial divisor, which is still 13, is greater than the remaining number, 29**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Python code:

```
num=600851475143
i=2 # Smallest prime factor
for k in range(0,num):
    if i >= num: # Prime factor of the number should not be greater than the number
        break
    elif num % i == 0: # Check if the number is evenly divisible by i
        num = num / i
    else:
        i= i + 1
print ("biggest prime number is: "+str(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
'''
import math

def isPrime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(x))):
        if not x%i:
           return False
    return True

def largest_factor(number):
    for i in range (2, int(math.sqrt(number))):
        if number%i == 0:
            number = number/i
            if isPrime(number) is True:
                max_val = number
                break
                print max_val
        else:
            i += 1
    return max_val

largest_factor(600851475143)
```

This actually compiles very fast. It checks for the number formed for being the prime number or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem using Python.

```
def lpf(x):
lpf=2
while (x>lpf):
    if (x%lpf==0):
        x=x/lpf

    else:
        lpf+=1
return x
print(lpf(600851475143))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 3
factor = []
number = 600851475143
while i * i <= number:
    if number % i != 0:
        i += 2
    else:
        number /= i
        factor.append(i)
while number >= i:
    if number % i != 0:
        i += 2
    else:
        number /= i
        factor.append(i)
print(max(factor))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my python code

```
a=2
list1=[]
while a<=13195:                     #replace 13195 with your input number
    if 13195 %a ==0:                #replace 13195 with your input number
        x , count = 2, 0
        while x <=a:
            if a%x ==0:
                count+=1
            x+=1
        if count <2:
            list1.append(a)
    a+=1

print (max(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my python code:

```
import math
ma = 600851475143
mn = 2
s = []
while mn < math.sqrt(ma):
    rez = ma / mn
    mn += 1
    if ma % mn == 0:
        s.append(mn)
print(max(s))
```

Comment: Hi Artem Chomkhalo, welcome. Please consider adding more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime_max(x):
a = x
i = 2
while i in range(2,int(a+1)):
    if a%i == 0:
        a = a/i
        
        if a == 1:
             print(i)
        i = i-1
    i = i+1
```

Comment: Posting code without explanation is not helpful. Moreover this does not answer the question: How to test OPs code correctness ? How OPs code is wrong ?

Comment: 1↑⌽(0=N|600851475143)/N←1↓⍳10000 (https://tryapl.org/)